# SAS - Scan through subset of database and populate array with unique values

Tags: sas

I have a set of unique set of Customer-IDs and purchases and need to condense them down into one observation for each customer encompassing every unique purchase they have made.

E.g.,

```
CustID Purchase1 Purchase2 Purchase3 Purchase4
J Bike Shoes Shirt Pants
J Shirt Pants null null
J Bike Helmet Pants null
K Shoes Helmet null null
L Basketball Shoes Shirt null
L Bike Helmet null null
```

I would like my output to look like:

```
CustID P1 P2 P3 P4 P5 P6 P7 P8 P9 P10 P11 P12 PN
J Bike Shoes Shirt Pants Helmet null null null null null null null
K Shoes Helmet null null ........  null
L Basketball Shoes Shirt Bike Helmet null .... null
```

I am okay with just setting a very large value for the maximum P such that I never hit it, but bonus points if someone can show me how to scan through the data-set and set a maximum value for P corresponding to the largest number of unique purchases for a given customer.

Comment: You might also find example 3 from [this paper](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings12/052-2012.pdf) interesting if you want to transpose multiple variables in one pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like this?
All the purchases on the same column, nodupkey for deleting repeated purchases by subject, returning on a row-based environment (the system will automatically choose the number of column naming them COL1 COL2 etc..)

```
/*sample dataset*/
data want;
   infile datalines delimiter=' '; 
   input CustID $ Purchase1 $ Purchase2 $ Purchase3 $ Purchase4 $;
   datalines;                      
J Bike Shoes Shirt Pants
J Shirt Pants null null
J Bike Helmet Pants null
K Shoes Helmet null null
L Basketball Shoes Shirt null
L Bike Helmet null null
;


/*every purchase on the same column*/   
data want01;
length purchase $200;
set want;
array purc[*] purchase:;
do i=1 to dim(purc);
PURCHALL=purc[i];
output;
end;
keep custid purchall;
run;

/*delete repeated purchases and blanks*/   
proc sort data=want01 out=want02 nodupkey; where purchall not in ('' 'null'); by custid purchall; run;

/*returning on a row based dataset*/ 
proc transpose data=want02 out=want03;
by custid;
var purchall;
run;
```

If you only want to gain the maximum number of unique purchases, simply apply a proc freq on WANT02 dataset (the one contaning unique purchases without blanks and nulls).

```
proc freq data=want02 noprint;
table custid /out=want04;
run;
```

WANT04 will be:

```
CUSTID | FREQUENCY |
--------------------
 J     |        5  | 
 K     |        2  |
 L     |        5  |
```

Comment: you're welcome, let me know if you need any further clarification.